# JavaScript array delete an element from an index

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

Hi folks I have the following array

```
const options = [
    'option one', 
    'option two', 
    'some other random string', 
    'another random string', 
    'option last one', 
]
```

If I want to remove something from the middle of this array which also update the indexes, I tried `delete arr[ind]` but that does not update the index. Want to completely remove from that array.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to filter it out by index.

```js
options.filter((item, index) => index !== 3);
```

Or by name:

```js
options.filter((item) => item !== 'option one');
```

Comment: It works for me in my terminal. How is it not working?

Comment: You need to reassign the above-mentioned expressions to a new variable and it will contain the old data minus the condition.

Comment: If for some reason, you have to keep the same array reference. you can simply use the ``splice`` method: ``options.splice(ind, 1)``

Answer (score 1):

you can use splice as

```
options.splice(index,1)
```

if you want to use the filter method you should store the result because filter method does not mutate the array on which it is called, but returns a new array.

Comment: Thank you @Hashem Taha, this is even better I would have accepted your answer but I have already accepted Joshua Obritsch answer.. thank you

Comment: Actually, I thought that because this thread was tagged with `reactjs`, it would be better not to mutate the array, as that wouldn't trigger a re-render. This is of course assuming the array is stored in `state`.